# Ms Access Query not return null values with * wildcard

Tags: ms-access

I've been banging my head over this one for a while, so hopefully someone can help me!

I have a simple query in MS Access that goes like this

```
Where [Param] like IIf(FormCondition,[SpecificParam],"*")
```

It works fine when the IIf condition is true, but when the condition is false it returns all rows where [Param] is not null, whereas I need ALL rows, including those where [Param] is null. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to wrap the entire condition in the `IIF`:

```
Where IIf(FormCondition, [Param] like [SpecificParam], True)
```

This will always return `True` if `FormCondition` is false.

An alternative formulation without `IIF` would be:

```
Where ([Param] like [SpecificParam] OR NOT FormCondition)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The first suggestion doesn't work (I read elsewhere that it has to do with the order VBA and SQL are executed). The second one does work, but I was trying to avoid it because the query builder creates a new row with a new column for FormCondition. Since I have quite a few of those, it will double many rows, but I guess there's no way around it. Thanks!